# Call recording in ionic version 1

Tags: ionic-framework

> How do I record call conversations in ionic framework version 1 ?  Is
>   it possible to record calls in ionic framework ?

Answer (score 2):

We can record calls with **cordova-media-plugin** plugin in android.
First install the media Plugin by executing the following command
**cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media**
Then goto the Plugin folder and traverse into the following file **“plugins\cordova-plugin-media\src\android\AudioPlayer.java”** . Here in the **startRecording** function we have line
**this.recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);** line number is 154
Change it to **this.recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);**

We can replace MIC with any audio source in the following link. for example **VOICE_COMMUNICATION,VOICE_DOWNLINK,VOICE_RECOGNITION** etc
*https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html*

Answer (score 0):

It's bit difficult but you can give a try to 
**[cordova-plugin-media-capture](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture)**

> This plugin provides access to the device's audio, image, and video
>   capture capabilities.

```
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, options);
```

also you can check **[Ionic forum's answers](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-record-conversations-in-phone/40377)** for reference.

Comment: Thanks codeMonkey. I used this "cordova-plugin-media-capture"  plugin. but its records only the dialer voice not the receiver voice. We need both of them voice.